# How do I find out who won the latest Splatfest?

Tags: splatoon-2

Ketchup obviously won the latest *Splatoon 2* Splatfest, but I just need to double check . Where do I look up ketchup's obvious victory?

Comment: I actually think mayo won.

Comment: @Fredy31 [I think that's the joke.](http://kotaku.com/mayo-won-splatfest-but-some-splatoon-2-players-worry-t-1797572693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Similar to Splatoon 1,  Splatfest hosts Perl and Marina will announce the results once the contest has ended. This is the only time Splatfest results are viewable in-game.**

[image]

If you want to view the Splatfest later on, you can find the results for your specific region on sites like [Splatoonwiki.org](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatfest#Splatoon_2_4) and [Splatoon Wikia](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Splatoon_2_Splatfest_information_and_results), or on [Nintendo's official Twitter account](https://twitter.com/NintendoAmerica/status/894078154846949376).

---

#### Splatfest Results for Mayo vs Ketchup

```
---North America and Oceania---
             Mayo     Ketchup
Votes        27%      73%
Solo Wins    52%      48%
Team Wins    51%      49%
Final Score: 2-1, Mayo Wins

---Europe---
             Mayo     Ketchup
Votes        34%      66%
Solo Wins    51%      49%
Team Wins    51%      49%
Final Score: 2-1, Mayo Wins


---Japan---
             Mayo     Ketchup
Votes        56%      44%
Solo Wins    51%      49%
Team Wins    49%      51%
Final Score: 2-1, Mayo Wins
```

Comment: It is also available in the Nintendo Switch App

Comment: @Fredy31 I wasn't aware of that. Do you mind if I add this information to my answer?

Comment: I remember seeing it, but wanted to go get a screenshot and can't find it anymore.

Comment: @Fredy31 *Game Specific Services → Splatoon 2 → My Stats → Splatfest Stats*. Feel free to either edit that information into my answer, or post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

If it's like splatoon 1, its gonna be in the next time you have an update by the sisters. They are gonna talk about it.

There are also wikis that keep track of the winners http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Splatoon_2_Splatfest_information_and_results